# Opening the localhost web from another device using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a python file that sends the response to the localhost website opened by the browser. This web can successfully open by the same device which hosts it, but when failed to be opened by the other device under the same LAN. Why does that happen?

I use `http.server` in Python3 to host the local server. I'm using these codes:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

hostName = "localhost"
hostPort = 9000

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        path = self.path
        print(path)
        referer = self.headers.get('Referer')
        print("The referer is", referer)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        # str is the html code I used
        self.wfile.write(bytes(str, "utf-8"))

myServer = HTTPServer((hostName, hostPort), MyServer)
print("Server Starts - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))

try:
    myServer.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

myServer.server_close()
print("Server Stops - %s:%s" % (hostName, hostPort))
```

I am able to open the web by using `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, but just not the ip address.

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use your machine's IP address instead of `localhost`(Loopback) as the host. If your machine's IP is `192.168.x.x` then the server will run at: `192.168.x.x:9000`.

Comment: Well, no, it still can not work for me. The connection always fails. But thanks for responding.

Comment: Can you ping your machine from the other machine/device you are trying to access?

Comment: I can not ping it, always shows `Unknown host`, even on the host machine. But I can `curl` the result. @salman

Comment: If you can not ping one machine from another machine in the same network, then you first need to check your network configuration.

Comment: Oh, I can access from another machine by changing the `hostName` to my ip address. However, I still cannot ping it. I think my network config is fine